# Should we provide a Spanish version of the "don't-ask" page in the Help center?

Tags: petición-de-funcionalidad, formulado-de-preguntas, centro-de-ayuda, traducción

Should we provide a Spanish version of the "don't-ask" page in the Help center?  It's called, [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).

I recently learned that our moderators can't change it without SE assistance.  My question is, should we prepare a translation and ask the moderators to intervene and request that SE post our translation?

There's no hurry to do this or decide it, but this question came up for me today so I thought I'd write it up while it's fresh in my mind.

Comment: Let's have it! Note we can use much of the translation available in SOes: [¿Qué tipo de preguntas debo evitar preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@fedorqui commented:

> Let's have it! Note we can use much of the translation available in SOes: [¿Qué tipo de preguntas debo evitar preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: We cannot edit it ourselves, but can ask CM to do so. I will do.

Answer (score 0):

*The material at SOes looks great but would benefit from some editing (I will bold the phrases needing links):*

#### ¿Qué tipo de preguntas se deben evitar aquí?

Antes que nada, verifica que tu pregunta sea **relevante para este sitio**.

Las preguntas de StackExchange deben ser prácticas y solucionables, y se deben basar en problemas reales que enfrentas. Hay que evitar las preguntas abiertas que inciten diálogo, porque disminuyen la utilidad de nuestro sitio y quitan espacio de la lista de preguntas de primera plana.

Las preguntas deben tener un alcance razonable. Si puedes imaginar un libro entero que responde a tu pregunta, estás pidiendo demasiado.

Si tu motivación para preguntar es “Quisiera participar en una discusión acerca de ______”, entonces esa pregunta no queda bien aquí. Por otro lado, si tu motivación es “Quisiera que me expliquen ______”, entonces la pregunta sí está bien planteada. (Tenemos una **página de chateo, *La Tertulia***, donde las discusiones abiertas son bienvenidas).

Para evitar que tu pregunta sea cerrada **y posiblemente eliminada**, evita hacer preguntas subjetivas en las que …

- todas las respuestas sean igualmente válidas: “¿Cuál es tu ______ favorito?”
- tu respuesta esté incluida en la pregunta, y esperes más respuestas: “Yo uso ______ para ______, ¿qué usan ustedes?”
- no haya ningún problema real que resolver: “Me pregunto si los demás opinan lo mismo que yo”
- la pregunta sea hipotética y abierta: “¿Qué pasaría si ______ ?"
- tu pregunta no sea más que una queja disfrazada: “______ apesta, verdad?”

(La sección anterior fue adaptada de las **FAQ de MetaFilter**.)

Ciertas preguntas subjetivas sí se permiten, pero ojo: tienen que ser *constructivas*:

- inspiran respuestas que expliquen el porqué, cuándo, y de qué manera
- tienden a tener respuestas largas (no súper cortas)
- tienen un tono constructivo, justo e imparcial
- invitan a compartir experiencias, no solo opiniones
- requieren que las opiniones sean respaldadas con hechos y referencias
- son más que la simple diversión sin valor educativo

Para más detalle, véanse los artículos de Jeff Atwood: ***Good Subjective, Bad Subjective*** y ***Real Questions Have Answers***.

Si tienes una duda acerca del funcionamiento del sitio en sí, por favor no preguntes aquí, sino en nuestro sitio de meta-discusiones, donde puedes ...

- preguntar si cierto tipo de pregunta es apropiado
- preguntar cuáles etiquetas se deben usar
- sugerir una funcionalidad
- reportar un error
- entender mejor, o proponer, cómo funciona, o cómo debe funcionar, este sitio